# How to get parent of Task in Sharepoint Designer or Infopath

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, infopath

When we create a subTask, we haven't got a number of Parent task. How to get Id of parent task on Sharepoint Designer or beter on InfoPath?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Designer, you can create a workflow and use Call HTTP Web Service action to get the parent ID:

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items?$select=Id,Title,ParentID/ID&$expand=ParentID&$filter=ID eq '[%CurrentItem:ID%]'
```